# How do I convert an array of floats to a byte[] and back?

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, arrays, endianness

I have an array of Floats that need to be converted to a byte array and back to a float[]... can anyone help me do this correctly?

I'm working with the bitConverter class and found myself stuck trying to append the results.

The reason I'm doing this is so I can save runtime values into a IO Stream.  The target storage is Azure Page blobs in case that matters.  I don't care about what endian this is stored in, as long as it input matches the output.

```
static  byte[] ConvertFloatToByteArray(float[] floats)
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[floats.Length * 4];// a single float is 4 bytes/32 bits

            for (int i = 0; i < floats.Length; i++)
            {
               // todo: stuck...I need to append the results to an offset of ret
                ret = BitConverter.GetBytes(floats[i]);

            }
            return ret;
        }


 static  float[] ConvertByteArrayToFloat(byte[] bytes)
{ //to do }
```

Comment: Could you work with serialization/deserialization to/from a memory stream? You could then get the `byte` array from the stream or construct a stream from a `byte` array.

Comment: Using the .Net serialization methods?  I'd rather not include any XML, and just take a raw bit-data... the system is pretty optimized and every bit is accounted for...

Comment: you can do binary serialization instead of XML serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx

Comment: @martinho - Just so I understand, will the serialized object have the exact same length as the array of floats?  In other words, will byte offset 4 always be the same as the passed in value of float[3] disregarding endianness?  No XML gunk?

Comment: It won't have XML in it, but it is probably overkill for this. I was just mentioning that you can do serialization without XML. I'm not sure about what the resulting byte array will be like, but it will work both ways without hassle.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

If you're looking for performance then you could use [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx). Nice and simple, and probably about as fast as you'll get in managed code.

```
var floatArray1 = new float[] { 123.45f, 123f, 45f, 1.2f, 34.5f };

// create a byte array and copy the floats into it...
var byteArray = new byte[floatArray1.Length * 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(floatArray1, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

// create a second float array and copy the bytes into it...
var floatArray2 = new float[byteArray.Length / 4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, floatArray2, 0, byteArray.Length);

// do we have the same sequence of floats that we started with?
Console.WriteLine(floatArray1.SequenceEqual(floatArray2));    // True
```

Comment: Awesome solution!!!!! I was going to multiply the float by like 10000000 and shift it, thus losing some precision. This is even better!

Comment: Instead of a literal `4` you can use `sizeof(float)`.

Comment: @NicholasTerry if you ever find yourself in the position of having to take the low-level road, instead of multiplying by a million, you can also store the float in its bit representation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 7):

There's the [**`BitConverter.ToSingle(byte[] value, int startIndex)`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-uk/library/system.bitconverter.tosingle.aspx)  method that should help out here.

> Returns a single-precision floating
>   point number converted from four bytes
>   at a specified position in a byte
>   array.

Your probably want something like (untested):

```
static float[] ConvertByteArrayToFloat(byte[] bytes)
{
    if(bytes == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");

   if(bytes.Length % 4 != 0)
        throw new ArgumentException
              ("bytes does not represent a sequence of floats");

    return Enumerable.Range(0, bytes.Length / 4)
                     .Select(i => BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i * 4))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

**EDIT**: Non-LINQ:

```
float[] floats = new float[bytes.Length / 4];

for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length / 4; i++)
    floats[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i * 4);

return floats;
```

Comment: I love linq as much as I don't understand it!  Which is a lot!   Since this will be a critical performance function, I'd like to use a system level object if possible.  Also the extension .ToArray() doesn't seem to exist in my .NET 4 command line project.  Do you know the namespace?

Comment: @makerofthings7: It's in `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

Comment: @maker: `System.Linq`, as always.

Comment: @marthinho Yes, have System.Linq but ToArray() didn't appear.  Odd

Comment: @makerofthings7: I was missing a parenthesis (fixed). That might have been the problem. Try now? Also, you might want to use the non-LINQ version if this is performance-critical. Profile both. :)

Answer (score 6):

You are not moving the position when you copy the float[i] into the byte array, you should write something like

```
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(float[i]),0,res,i*4);
```

instead of just:

```
ret = BitConverter.GetBytes(floats[i]);
```

the inverse function follow the same strategy.

Comment: last parameter is 4 for Array.Copy.  +1 I would mark this as the answer to the question (since it addresses the question in the title), but Ani gave so much time into his answer.  Only a 5 point difference anyway...

Answer (score 3):

```
static float[] ConvertByteArrayToFloat(byte[] bytes)
{
    if(bytes.Length % 4 != 0) throw new ArgumentException();

    float[] floats = new float[bytes.Length/4];
    for(int i = 0; i < floats.Length; i++)
    {
        floats[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, i*4);
    }

    return floats;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access a float (or other) array directly as bytes with a union and avoid BitConverter altogether. More on C# unions here [How to create a C/C++ union by using attributes in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/how-to-create-a-c-cpp-union-by-using-attributes)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// create an array of 100 floats and set values
const int floatCount = 100;
var arrayUnion = new ArrayUnion(floatCount * sizeof(float));
for (var n = 0; n < floatCount; ++n)
    arrayUnion.floatArray[n] = n;

// write the byte array to a file
var filename = "c:/temp/testwrite.bin";
using (FileStream stream = new(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
    stream.Write(arrayUnion.byteArray, 0, arrayUnion.byteArray.Length);
    }

// read the byte array back and write out the float values
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    stream.Read(arrayUnion.byteArray, 0, arrayUnion.byteArray.Length);

    for (var n = 0; n < floatCount; ++n)
        Console.WriteLine(arrayUnion.floatArray[n]);
    }

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct ArrayUnion(int byteCount) {
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteCount];

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public float[] floatArray;
    }
```