# Write float array into a binary file c#

Tags: c#, matlab, file, binary, floating-point

I have a float array :

```
float[] samples32array
```

I need to convert it into a binary file so I can read it in matlab.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well do you have any documentation as to the format that Matlab expects?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html?refresh=true#bt3twl9-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx) to write the data to a file very easily:

```
foreach (var value in samples32array)
{
    writer.Write(value);
}
```

Now `BinaryWriter` is guaranteed to use little-endian format, so in your Matlab call, you should specify a `machinefmt` value of `l` to explicitly read it in little-endian format too.

Comment: Hello Jon, I use matlab to read the file like this: 

    fid = fopen('myRecordBin.bin', 'r');
fread(fid,inf,'float',4,'l');

Now, I can read it and matlab's workspace show 69222 elements and in the vector it shows: 69222x1 double.

But my original float array(and not double) in c# is twice: 138444 elements. 
Is something wrong with my reading?

Answer (score 5):

It's simple. First, you should use [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and create a file. Then, you can use [`BinaryWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter(v=vs.110).aspx), which can write any C# datatype into an underlaying stream, such as a `FileStream`.

```
using (FileStream file = File.Create(path))
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
        foreach (float value in samples32array)
        {
            writer.Write(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the constructor of `BinaryWriter` accepts the basic type `Stream`, any stream type can be used. It works for file streams as well as `NetworkStream` or a `MemoryStream` etc. It's a very generic class.

And please avoid converting the `float[]` into a `byte[]` beforehand as it will allocate memory and this is bad if your array is big (don't know if that's the case for you).

Comment: `using System.IO;`

Answer (score 1):

[This SO answer shows a way to convert a float array into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4636735/579148). Then you can use [File.WriteAllBytes() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) to write it out to a file. How MatLab reads it, though, will be the issue.

I found [some documentation for MatLab for the `fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) command. It looks like is has some arguments that will allow you to define the precision of the read. You may be able to use "float" as the precision value. Though, the is a bit of an educated guess as I am not very familiar with MatLab.