# How to convert stored MP3 file data (byte[]) into a float[] Unity can use as AudioSource-Data?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, mp3, naudio

I did tons of research during the last days and nothing helped me out for my special problem. I am writing my own music engine for a Unity3d game and for this I created custom files containing the mp3 data and other information.

What I'm trying to do now is to take these split up mp3-byte-arrays *(which can be played when I store them individually, I tested it - so the audio data seems to be fine)* and convert them to Unity's AudioSource(s) somehow. I think converting the byte[] into a float[] containing the needed sample data of my audio would be enough, because `audioClip.setData( ... );` should do the trick then (I hope).

But I continuously fail at decompressing and/or converting my raw mp3 buffer[] to anything like float[] - and even if I somehow succeed, the only thing I hear is nasty whitenoise-like nonsense.

Any ideas? I would love to hear from you and solve this problem!

Comment: Convert to wav first then use leftchannel, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114885/how-do-i-play-mp3-files-in-unity-standalone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an array of floats to a byte\[\] and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back)

Comment: Thx @LukeHutton - This helped me out! Don't know how i could miss this post... Actually i didn't just take leftchannel, i merged leftchannel and rightchannel to get stereo information. Thx alot!

Comment: Nice! good luck

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of a decompression algorithm that will take a compressed MP3 stream and output it as uncompressed data  is not a trivial task. You can either find a library that does this (I am not aware of any), or work around the issue in some way.
You can use untiy engine to decompress (aka play back) through an AudioSource, and sample it then, or execute some FFMPEG command line to get the wav. Most ways of doing it are cumbersome and ideally you should find a way of not doing it at all.

byte[] or float[] is not really a signifficant difference here - the difference is encoded vs raw