# exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' was thrown c# with OpenGL

Tags: c#, opengl

```
public Color getPixelColor(OpenGL gl, int x, int y) 
{
    Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    byte[] pixels = new byte[3];               
    gl.ReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, OpenGL.GL_RGB, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    int a = pixels[0], b = pixels[1], c = pixels[2];
    color.setColor(pixels[0], pixels[1], pixels[2]);              
}
```

I use `gl.ReadPixels()` to get pixel Color but I have problem that `exception of type 'system.stackoverflowexception' was thrown at line 'gl.ReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, OpenGL.GL_RGB, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, pixels);`.

Can you help me fix that error, please?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with 3 bytes, but you're trying to read 3 (RGB) floats which is 12 bytes. Change the array from type byte to type float.

Comment: thanks,
glReadPixels require parameter that is byte[] pixels, I changed from OpenGL.GL_FLOAT to OpenGL.GL_BYTE but didn't

Comment: Then you should make your byte array size 12 and keep GL_FLOAT.

Comment: it's that?
       public Color getPixelColor(OpenGL gl, int x, int y) 
        {
            Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            float[] pixels = new float[12];               
            gl.ReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, OpenGL.GL_RGB, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, pixels);             
            color.setColor(pixels[0], pixels[1], pixels[2]);              
            return color;   
        }

Comment: You said parameter is byte[], then it should be: `byte[] pixels = new byte[12];`. And because it's byte you will have to convert it to float after, before returning your color.

Comment: yes, so how to convert from byte array pixels to float?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back

Comment: I tried to follow the instructions but when debeg still no exception. I am working on a color scheme for the shap with the Flood Fill algorithm, this function is used to get the color of the pixel, to check out the color and to make the spangle.