# How to encode .JPG file from a Tensor with TensorFlowSharp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tensorflowsharp

I want save .`JPG` image file from a Tensor with `TensorFlowSharp`. I tried `GetValue()` to get the value of tensor, but I always met an issue `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

the issue shown in unity is below:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>   TensorFlowModel.CallTFmodel.CallTFmodel_Start (System.Byte[] originalbytes, System.String SendPathName) (at Assets/Sample/Glass/Scripts/CallTFmodel.cs:84)
>   Camera2picture+d__9.MoveNext () (at Assets/Sample/Glass/Scripts/Camera2picture.cs:71)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)

```
var runner = session.GetRunner();

// "input", "ps";
runner.AddInput(graph["images"][0], tensorNormalized).Fetch(graph["Tanh"][0]); 
var output = runner.Run();
var result = output[0];

// the issue is happened here. 
byte[] result_bytes = (byte[])result.GetValue(jagged:true); 
// my target is to use GetValue() to transform tensor to array with type byte.
// this line is to write the byte array to a image file.
File.WriteAllBytes(SendPathName, result_bytes);
```

My target is to find a way to save a tensor to .JPG image file with TensorFlowSharp, but unfortunately I try many times cannot find a solution to do it.

Comment: well what is the type returned by `result.GetValue` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an array of floats to a byte\[\] and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TensorflowSharp you can do it like this:

```
    private byte[] TensorToBitmap(TFTensor image)
    {
        var graph = new TFGraph();
        var input = graph.Placeholder(TFDataType.Float);
        var output = graph.Cast(input, TFDataType.UInt8);
        output = graph.EncodeJpeg(output);

        using (var session = new TFSession(graph))
        {
            var result = session.Run(
                inputs: new[] { input },
                inputValues: new[] { image },
                outputs: new[] { output });

            var tensor = result[0];
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)tensor.TensorByteSize - 10];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(tensor.Data + 10, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            return buffer;
        }
    }
```

I dont know why, but you have to skip the first 10 bytes.

Comment: Thanks, I can use File.WriteAllBytes(SendPathName, result_bytes); to get a .JPG file, but it can not be opened. 
byte[] result_bytes = TensorToBitmap(result, 864); 
File.WriteAllBytes(SendPathName, result_bytes);

private byte[] TensorToBitmap(TFTensor image, int imagesize)
        {// the code is same as above you put.
            return buffer;
            }
        }

Comment: the error is “Could not open .jpg it may be corrupted, or may use the "Preview" unrecognized file format correspondence”