# How to convert float value to byte in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, byte, converters, bitconverter

I want to convert 794.328247 value to byte.

I used Convert.ToByte(794.328247) but it showing following error,

Error : - Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.

So anyone can help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: You've tagged `BitConverter` but you're not using `BitConverter` (which would give you what you want)...

Comment: you will need `BitConverter.GetBytes(794.328247);`. It will return a `byte[ ]` as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back), which would make a great duplicate ;)

Comment: What is expected output here? Byte gives you 8-bit unsigned integer where range is in between `0 to 255`

Comment: Your code be like https://i.imgflip.com/598eem.png

Comment: you cannot convert a float into a single byte - or at least not every float and without loss. You can convert it to an array of bytes, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an array of floats to a byte\[\] and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back)

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635769/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-floats-to-a-byte-and-back

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [Bitconverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0#System_BitConverter_GetBytes_System_Single_)

```
byte[ ] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes( 794.328247);
```

Note that this produce an array of bytes since a float is 32bit, so it needs 4 bytes to store it. Do the reverse with [ToSingle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=net-5.0).

The alternative is to truncate the float: `var b = (byte) 794.328247;`, but this is usually not a good idea since a byte has a far smaller range of values that a float. In some cases you might need to first normalize the input value to some range of values before truncating. I.e. you would remap values from say 750-800 to the 0-255 range.